# I get error :embed.description is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I get error embed.description is not a function and I dont know why
I try  to do command that write a random command

```
    name: 'random game',
    description: "All commands",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        let Games = [

            "Fortnite",
            "Overwatch",
            "Among us",
            "Rocket league",
            "Fall guys",
            "Spellbreak",
            "Counter Strike Global Offensive",
            "Minecraft",
            "Valorant",
        ]
            embed.setTitle("Random Game");
            embed.description(`You should play ${(Games[Math.floor(Math.random() * (Games.length))])}`);
                embed.setColor("RANDOM");
                return message.channel.send(embed)

    }
    
}
```

Comment: it's `embed.setDescription()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need embed help, the Discord.JS docs can be very helpful.

Here is a sample embed that uses every method in the `#messageEmbed()` obj:

```js
// at the top of your file
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Also, your error (as mentioned above) is that it is `#setDescription()`